# How to find documents that their data match a condition on at least one item from a given array of items - mongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to fetch records that exists in provided dates array.

This provided array of dates will fetch records between start & end date.

Example:

I have this schema:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "course": "Maths",
        "startDate": "2022-06-07",
        "endDate": "2022-06-12"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "course": "Chemistry",
        "startDate": "2022-06-06",
        "endDate": "2022-06-09"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "course": "Physics",
        "startDate": "2022-06-08",
        "endDate": "2022-06-10"
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "course": "Computer Science",
        "startDate": "2022-06-10",
        "endDate": "2022-06-18"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5",
        "course": "Computer Science",
        "startDate": "2022-06-10",
        "endDate": "2022-06-13"
    },
    {
        "_id": "6",
        "course": "Biology",
        "startDate": "2022-06-08",
        "endDate": "2022-06-10"
    }
]
```

Provided array:

```
["2022-06-06", "2022-06-17"]
```

The expected response is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "course": "Chemistry",
        "startDate": "2022-06-06",
        "endDate": "2022-06-09"
    },
    {
        "_id": "4",
        "course": "Computer Science",
        "startDate": "2022-06-10",
        "endDate": "2022-06-18"
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me with the query? Thanks

Comment: You want to fetch records if either the startDate or endDate of the records exists in the array you provided?

Comment: the provided array will be 2 dates always? also what you want to keep, documents that exact match start and end date? or documents that their start/end date are inside those limits of the array? Also i think you should save normal dates in the database, not strings

Comment: @SeeratAhmed I need this array to fall between start & end dates

Comment: @Takis it can be multiple dates, and these multiple dates should fall between start & end date

Answer (score 3):

You can use an aggregation pipeline with `$filter`:

1. Add the array of dates to the documents
2. Add a `matchingDates` field that counts the items in the `dates` array that matches the condition.
3. `$match` only documents that have such items.
4. Format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {dates: ["2022-06-06", "2022-06-17"]}},
  {
    $set: {
      matchingDates: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$dates",
            as: "item",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {$gte: [{$toDate: "$$item"}, {$toDate: "$startDate"}]},
                {$lte: [{$toDate: "$$item"}, {$toDate: "$endDate"}]}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {matchingDates: {$gt: 0}}},
  {$unset: ["dates", "matchingDates"]}
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5fGSaYwm9oO)

Comment: This seems to be working fine, I will have it checked in detail, can you please explain each part of query a bit for a better understanding aswell? Thanks

Comment: What if i want to add conditions to the query like, course == "Maths" && isDeleted === false?

Comment: For example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kiGCJ9flcH6